# Group by a column ('tenant') and get the max consecutive 1s in ('value') column

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

I have a df shown below:

| Tenant | Value |
| --- | --- |
| x | 1 |
| x | 1 |
| x | 0 |
| x | 1 |
| y | 1 |
| y | 0 |

Results:
Tenant X should be 2 and tenant y should be 1

I am trying to get the max consecutive value 1s per group. If there are any 0 in between the value 1 the count starts over.
I am new to python and not sure where to start. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
def max_ones(col):
    return col.groupby(col.diff().ne(0).cumsum()).sum().max()

result = df.groupby("Tenant").Value.agg(max_ones)
```

If the `Value` column can have other values than `0` or `1` you should rather use:

```
result = df.assign(Value=df.Value.eq(1)).groupby("Tenant").Value.agg(max_ones)
```